# Exit PowerShell script using 'exit' kills my program completely

Tags: powershell

I am using a form window to get some input from a user and I am asking in a do-while loop if the input is correct (like this:)

```
while(($ParID -ne 6) -or ($Research_Groups -ne 3) -or ($Customer -lt 1) -or ($Projectname -lt 1))
```

The problem with this request is that I wanna ask if the field is **empty** but if he presses cancel without entering anything the window will open again like a **while(true)** loop...

I have also made a cancel button to **'exit'** the programm where I did put (yeah you guessed right) an exit behind this button and my problem is that PowerShell throws me an error that the programm has crashed so I am searching for a save way to **stop** my programm from crashing!

```
 $objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") #Escape (ESC) -> when the key 'Escape (ESC)' has been pressed then the window closes
        {$objForm.Close()}}) #windowclose -> closes the window
```

this it he error it throws:

[image]

```
DO {

    $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form #init -> initializing window form

    $objForm.Text = "Input Window v0.5" #name -> the name which will be display in the top border of the window

    $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,250) #size -> set the size of the window

    $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" #location -> where the window will appear on the screen

    $objForm.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D' #sizing -> fixes the size of the window so you cannot make it bigger

#objForm Keys -> here are the keys 'Enter' and 'Escape (ESC)' defined to the buttons 'OK' and 'Cancel'

    $objForm.KeyPreview = $True

    $objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") #Enter -> when the key 'Enter' has been pressed read out the input fields and assign them to variables

        {$ParID=$ParIDInbox.Text;$Research_Groups=$ResearchGroupInbox.Text;$Customer=$CustomerInbox.Text;$Projectname=$ProjectnameInbox.Text;$objForm.Close()}}) #variables -> assigns the variables

    $objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") #Escape (ESC) -> when the key 'Escape (ESC)' has been pressed then the window closes

        {$objFOrm.Close()}}) #windowclose -> closes the window

#OKButton -> creates a button with the value 'OK'

    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button #initialization -> initializes the button

    $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,180) #Location -> where the button is located in the window

    $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23) #Size -> defines the size of the button

    $OKButton.Text = "OK" #value -> sets the value of the button to 'OK'

    $OKButton.Add_Click({$ParID=$ParIDInbox.Text;$Research_Groups=$ResearchGroupInbox.Text;$Customer=$CustomerInbox.Text;$Projectname=$ProjectnameInbox.Text;$objForm.Close()}) #variables -> assigns the variables

    $objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton) #adding -> adds the button to the window

#CancelButton -> creates a button with the value 'Cancel'

    $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button #initialization -> initializes the button

    $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,180) #Location -> where the button is located in the window

    $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23) #Size -> defines the size of the button

    $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel" #value -> sets the value of the button to 'Cancel'

    $CancelButton.Add_Click({$objFOrm.Close()}) #closing -> closes the window after clicked

    $objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton) #adding -> adds the button to the window

#ParID_Label -> creates a Label for the 'Par ID' input field

    $ParIDLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label #initialization -> initializes the label

    $ParIDLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $ParIDLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) #Size -> defines the size of the label

    $ParIDLabel.Text = "Par ID (6 numbers!)" #value -> sets the value of the Label to 'Par ID (6 numbers)'

    $objForm.Controls.Add($ParIDLabel) #adding -> adds the label to the window

#ParID Input Box -> Input box for the Par ID input

    $ParIDInbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox #initialization -> initializes the input box

    $ParIDInbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,30) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $ParIDInbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) #Size -> defines the size of the inputbox

    $objForm.Controls.Add($ParIDInbox) #adding -> adds the input box to the window

#Research Group Label -> creates a Label for the 'Research Group' input field

    $ResearchGroupLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label #initialization -> initializes the label

    $ResearchGroupLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $ResearchGroupLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) #Size -> defines the size of the label

    $ResearchGroupLabel.Text = "Research Group (3 letters!)" #value -> sets the value of the Label to 'Research Group (3 letters!)'

    $objForm.Controls.Add($ResearchGroupLabel) #adding -> adds the label to the window

#Research Group Input Box -> Input box for the Research Group input

    $ResearchGroupInbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox #initialization -> initializes the input box

    $ResearchGroupInbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,70) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $ResearchGroupInbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) #Size -> defines the size of the inputbox

    $objForm.Controls.Add($ResearchGroupInbox)  #adding -> adds the input box to the window

#Customer Label -> creates a Label for the 'Customer' input field

    $CustomerLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label #initialization -> initializes the label

    $CustomerLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,90) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $CustomerLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) #Size -> defines the size of the label

    $CustomerLabel.Text = "Customer" #value -> sets the value of the Label to 'Customer'

    $objForm.Controls.Add($CustomerLabel) #adding -> adds the label to the window

#Customer Input Box -> Input box for the Customer input   

    $CustomerInbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox #initialization -> initializes the input box

    $CustomerInbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,110) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $CustomerInbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) #Size -> defines the size of the inputbox

    $objForm.Controls.Add($CustomerInbox) #adding -> adds the input box to the window

#Projectname Label -> creates a Label for the 'Projectname' input field      

    $ProjectnameLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label #initialization -> initializes the label

    $ProjectnameLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,130) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $ProjectnameLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) #Size -> defines the size of the label

    $ProjectnameLabel.Text = "Projectname"  #value -> sets the value of the Label to 'Projectname'

    $objForm.Controls.Add($ProjectnameLabel) #adding -> adds the label to the window

#Projectname Input Box -> Input box for the Projectname input

    $ProjectnameInbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox #initialization -> initializes the input box

    $ProjectnameInbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,150) #Location -> where the label is located in the window

    $ProjectnameInbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) #Size -> defines the size of the inputbox 

    $objForm.Controls.Add($ProjectnameInbox) #adding -> adds the input box to the window 

    $objForm.Topmost = $True #topmost -> A topmost form is a form that overlaps all the other (non-topmost!) forms!

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$checkInputs =  {
    (($using:ParID -ne 6) -or 
    ($using:Research_Groups -ne 3) -or 
    ($using:Customer -lt 1) -or 
    ($using:Projectname -lt 1)) -and
    !$using:Exit
}

while(Invoke-Command $checkInputs)
{
    exit
}

} while($ParID)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `break` instead of exit? This will stop your While loop.
Or, if you need to exit your program entirely, you should dispose your active form `$Form.Dispose()` instaed of brutal `exit`.

**EDIT:**

In most cases you should not create and spawn your form itself inside do/while loop. In my opinion it's better to use while for checks not for the entire form. That is how I imagine that:

```
#OKButton -> creates a button with the value 'OK'
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button #initialization -> initializes the button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,180) #Location -> where the button is located in the window
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23) #Size -> defines the size of the button
$OKButton.Text = "OK" #value -> sets the value of the button to 'OK'

$OKButton_OnClick = {

    if (
        ($ParIDInbox.Text.Length -lt 6) -or
        ($ResearchGroupInbox.Text.Length -lt 3) -or
        [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($CustomerInbox.Text) -or
        [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ProjectnameInbox.Text.Length)
    ) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please fill out all of the form fields", "ERROR", 
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
    }
    else {
        $ParID=$ParIDInbox.Text
        $Research_Groups=$ResearchGroupInbox.Text
        $Customer=$CustomerInbox.Text
        $Projectname=$ProjectnameInbox.Text

        Write-Host -f Yellow "$ParID | $Research_Groups | $Customer | $Projectname"

        $objForm.Dispose()
    }
}

$OKButton.Add_Click($OKButton_OnClick) #variables -> assigns the variables
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton) #adding -> adds the button to the window
```

The code above works for me. Have just checked.

If you need to call your form multiple times just call it in a while loop - dont recreate it. Everytime you call the form it takes default values for the form objects. It's better to check form fields, not the variables you provide values to.

```
while ($condition) {
    $objForm.ShowDialog()
}

$objForm.Dispose()
```

**EDIT2:**

More bright ideas: you do not need to check values length - you can set the MaxLength parameter for them

```
$ParIDInbox.MaxLength = 6
$ResearchGroupInbox.MaxLength = 3
```

Comment: So after trying:    'break' throws the same error as mentioned in the question / '$Form.Dispose()' works like '$Form.Close()' and the problem about those 2 is that if I am currently in the loop it closes them and then just opens again...

Comment: Well... looking at your code I cant imagine why there's any reason to summon form in a while loop %) And to use `while` inside `while`. Thats an absurd and a very bad practice. Seriously.

Comment: come down man ^^ That was my code from more than 1 hour ago I changed it :D

Comment: and where should I 'summon'  my form instead?

Comment: To answer this I should understand why do you wrap all the form code into a Do/While loop at the first place. In most cases you need `while` while checking conditions. I added some code to my answer (after 'EDIT') to clarify.

Comment: I copied pasted big parts because I don't really code powershell but ín the last few days I had to learn it

Comment: you mean I just need this :

Comment: `while ($condition) {`
    `$objForm.ShowDialog()`
`}` in order to open the window every time I want to? Btw what do you mean with "messagebox error feedback" could you show me an example ?

Comment: No. You need `while` only if you need to create the form multiple times with some condition. I prefer to use `foreach` or `for` to create form multiple times based on the input collection.

Comment: you got good ideas could you help me with that a bit? and btw when I copy that this "onclick" does not work for me

Comment: I wanted to recreate it because I wanted to make sure the inputs aren't wrong like 'empty' or so but when I ask that my cancel button also gets blocked because I am resummoning the from and my cancel button just closes the form (because when I write 'exit' behind that button the script totally crashes!

Comment: Edited my answer again. Please see updated EDIT and EDIT2. `you got good ideas` - Thanks for that. Just had to create lots of powershell-forms-apps not so long ago %)

Comment: I normally create java programs and sometimes android apps but since my last one crashed my smartphone I didn't touch android app creating anymore ^^

Comment: have you worked with sharepoint powershell apps? like checking in and out files because this is the last thing I need for my program to work fully and all those across the world wide web (xDDDDD funny) are pretty bad because they are all for 2010 and high but I **have** to work on **_sharepoint 2007_**

Comment: No unfortunately not. Havent worked with sharepoint at all :-(

Comment: but maybe you know this button onclick doesn't work for me?

Comment: because it just keeps displaying me that error :(                                          Method invocation failed because [System.String] doesn't contain a method named 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace'.
At C:\Users\z003ntuh\Desktop\OfferScriptPowershell.ps1:229 char:45
+                 [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace <<<< ($CustomerInbox.Text) -or
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (IsNullOrWhiteSpace:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: It's because I use PowerShell 5.0 and you obviously have 2.0 :) You can try `IsNullOrEmpty` method instead of `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Comment: thanks man and yeah my company has 2.0 (because my company is **very** slow doing such things ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could also set a bool e.g. `$Exit` and check it within your while condition:

```
$checkInputs =  {
    (($using:ParID -ne 6) -or 
    ($using:Research_Groups -ne 3) -or 
    ($using:Customer -lt 1) -or 
    ($using:Projectname -lt 1)) -and
    !$using:Exit
}

while(Invoke-Command $checkInputs)
{
    # do your things here
}
```

Comment: be back in a minute I'm gonna try this out

Comment: but my problem is still that I cannot get out of my program I mean yeah I can get out but also if I don't enter anything and press 'OK'

Comment: Well, You didn't shared your whole script with us thats why I don't know which type of form you are using. But you probably want to  `$objForm.Close()`

Comment: The problem is the script is more than 800 lines and that is a bit much and yeah I am doing $objForm.Close() already but this one throws me back to my window if there is a wrong input

Comment: okay it works fine but how do I check if OK is pressed because when there is no input and you press ok you should try it again (so the loop should start again

Comment: I can't tell you with the information you provided.

Comment: I posted my full loop above where the whole window is in :D